# How to capture/save logs from XACT_ABORT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following structure:

```
DECLARE @TranName VARCHAR(20) = 'TransName';
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRANSACTION @TranName
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(1); -- For example

    COMMIT TRANSACTION @TranName
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @TranName
    INSERT INTO LogErrors VALUES(@TranName, CAST(ERROR_LINE() as VARCHAR) + ' - ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(), GETDATE());
END CATCH
```

But I just capture `ERROR_MESSAGES()` from `TRY/CATCH` structure, I need to capture messages/logs from `XACT_ABORT` too.

I saw on `Log Viewer` the following statment:

```
Executed as user: SERVER/sqlprod. Unspecified error occurred on SQL Server. Connection may have been terminated by the server. [SQLSTATE HY000] (Error 0). The step failed.
```

I need to capture this message and save on my table `LogErrors`, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article on how to read the event logs

[Reading the SQL Server log files using TSQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1476/reading-the-sql-server-log-files-using-tsql/)

You can tweak the samples there to do what you want

Comment: Thats nice, but I cant execute the procedure `xp_ReadErrorLog`, I don't have this permission.

Comment: Then you won't be able to do what you want.  You apparently lack permissions.